# Need macro to Replace each character with a Pipe and display it in adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need a Macro to replace each character in a cell with a Pipe and the same should be displayed in the adjacent cells.

For example if cell A1 contains "Apple" the adjacent cells should display the replacement of each character i.e., cell B1 = |pple ; cell C1 = A|ple ; cell D1 = Ap|le ......

```
   A    |   B    |    C   |    D   |    E   |    F   | 
 ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
 Apple  | |pple  | A|ple  | Ap|le  | App|e  | Appl|  |
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What isn't working with what you have tried?  (And why on earth do you need to do this !?!??!)

Comment: @YowE3K I get stuck at adding loop, so I discarded the macro which I wrote. I've started learning macro recently. (and I just need it... for work)

Comment: How much is your employer going to pay us to work for him/her?  (And why does he/she need a macro rather than just a simple formula in Excel?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR(), vT()
    Dim s As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Integer
    vDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 30)
    For i = 1 To n
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        ReDim vT(1 To Len(s))
        For j = 1 To Len(s)
            vT(j) = Mid(s, j, 1)
        Next j
        For j = 1 To Len(s)
            vT(j) = "|"
            vR(i, j) = Join(vT, "")
            vT(j) = Mid(s, j, 1)
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("b1").Resize(n, 30) = vR
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You very much.... its working... 
I've a doubt... Have you limited it to 30 Columns in the array?

Comment: @Asghar, I did not know the length of the word, so I gave enough room.

Comment: FWIW - using VBA's `Mid` function would allow you to replace the inside of the `For i` loop with `s = vDB(i, 1): For j = 1 To Len(s): vR(i, j) = s: Mid(vR(i, j), j, 1) = "|": Next j`.  That would eliminate the need for splitting the string into individual characters and then the `Join` to get it back to a string.

Comment: @YowE3K, Thanks for comment.